# Common ways for pair matching of users in a database?

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, database-design

hope you are safe and well!
I have a question about regular or common ways of pair-matching if there is a database of users: say there are a few properties of each user, and when matching, each user could change the filtering options to only match those who fit their own requirement(so there is mutual selection between users), and we want to efficiently match 1000 users as precisely as possible.

For example, let's say there are 3 properties of every user: gender(female/male/other), study level(elementary/mediate/advanced), and grade(freshman/sophomore/junior/senior), and when matching, each user could choose to only match with people with their selected gender, study level and grade.
When focusing on 1 user, I could guess, on the perspective of database, we could use the filtering options in commands and get a list of those who satisfy both "my requirement" and "I fit their requirement"? However, I think this would be slow and asynchronous problems when there are 1000+ users in the matching phase at the same time?

I saw another post here discussed the blossom algorithm or greedy algorithm, which seem cool since if looking in a graph. Are they doable in this case? I guess if two users mutually fit both requirements, they would have an edge between the two nodes, and the value of edge could be comprehensive matching scores of 3 properties all together?

Anyway, I'm wondering is there a common way to do the pair matching precisely with at least 1000+ users at the same time?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is that each match has to have the exact same properties, then the solution is fairly simple; just do a multiple criteria sort (ex. first sort by gender, then within each gender category sort by study level, etc.) and pair the identical users.

However, in a random dataset you're very unlikely to have perfect matches for all users. In that case you would want score pairs by how closely each category matches and use a more complex algorithm to maximize your overall matches. What you would do depends heavily on your use case and userbase size. Honestly, 1000 users is a very small number for modern computers; pretty much any polynomial time method (including blossom as you mentioned) would work fine.